# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqEasyCounter'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've read a couple of these errors and it is apparently because people do not link to the scripts correctly, but I think my links are fine.

Here's the snippets:

in default.js (to reduce clutter) I ALSO TRIED JUST PUTTING IT ON THE HTML WITH SCRIPT TAGS.

```
//character counters
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.count1').jqEasyCounter({  //Error here: default.js:147 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqEasyCounter'
        'maxChars': 500,
        'maxCharsWarning': 50,
        'msgFontSize': '10px',
        'msgFontColor': '#F00',
        'msgFontFamily': 'Arial',
        'msgWarningColor': '#000'
    });
});
```

and the references:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.jqEasyCharCounter.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/default.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/history.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8"/>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
            src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <!-- jQuery UI -->
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
            src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
 <!-- jQuery UI CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />
```

Firebug/Chrome Inspect Element is finding the javascript files for it which should be `jquery.jqEasyCharCounter.js` and `default.js`.

Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

should be the first script to load, move it to the top before:

```
<script ...src="scripts/jquery.jqEasyCharCounter.js"></script>
```

Comment: err checking again, cause I got an error with another function... sorry

Comment: thanks that was it, i just had to juggle the order around a bit since I have other scripts (like jqueryUI for example).